# Does move_group.plan(sampleJointTargetPose) implement MoveJ by default?

Tags: ros, moveit, universal-robots, move-group-interface, ur10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a `UR10` real robot. I am **not** using `Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver` for robot control. I am using `moveit move_group` to do collision check for a pair of start_state and goal_state in joint-space. I am simply using move_group.plan() method to figure out if a collision-free path exists between the two states. It works. But, we control the robot using MoveJ commands, So I am trying to figure out if the collision-free path that is generated by the `move_group.plan()` and the paths that are in-general generated by `MoveJ` command are both same?

If not, what is the correct way of doing this?

if yes, is there a better way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367169/does-move_group.plan(samplejointtargetpose)-implement-movej-by-default?/) by [srujan](https://answers.ros.org/users/51644/srujan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2020-12-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`move_group.plan()` and the `MoveJ` command are not the same. `MoveJ` moves directly to the target in joint space (PTP motion), while `move_group.plan()` submits a planning request to whichever planning plugin is connected to MoveIt. The default planning plugin is sampling-based (RRTConnect in OMPL), but when there are no obstacles, it returns a direct motion in joint space just like `MoveJ`, which is probably the source of your confusion. If there *are* obstacles, the result of `move_group.plan()` can be very different from `MoveJ`.

If you want to plan motions like `MoveJ` (linear in joint space/configuration space) and `MoveL` (linear in cartesian space), you can use the [pilz_industrial_motion_planner](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/pilz_industrial_motion_planner.html) plugin which was recently merged into MoveIt. It has not been backported to melodic yet, so you would need to build MoveIt from source. I suggest using an [underlay workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) ([more details](https://answers.ros.org/question/330040/how-to-install-single-packages-in-a-workspace/)) with MoveIt inside to alleviate build time.

If you send a `PTP` [motion planning request](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/pilz_industrial_motion_planner.html#the-ptp-motion-command) to the `pilz_industrial_motion_planner` plugin and the plan succeeds, then moving your robot with the `MoveJ` command to the same target should be safe (if you represented your whole scene correctly and did not make mistakes).

In theory you could also çreate your own RobotTrajectory by linearly interpolating the joint poses between your start and goal and then [check if the path is valid](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/moveit_core/html/classplanning__scene_1_1PlanningScene.html#a70c5d8b01c2bbdf5515d790326590b38), but I would use the industrial motion planning plugin as described above, to avoid duplicating work. Using PTP/LIN/CIRC motions in MoveIt should soon become a lot easier.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2020-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [srujan](https://answers.ros.org/users/51644/srujan/) on 2020-12-14**:
Thanks for your response @fvd. It was indeed useful. However, I am unable to use the `pilz_industrial_motion_planner` plugin. Here's what I did:

- created a new workspace with moveit melodic-devel build from source. build successful
- created a new workspace (pilz_ws) and underlayed melodic_source_moveit1. I installed `pilz_common` and `pilz_industrial_motion` packages, build successful. tried installing `pilz_robots` . build unsuccessful, hence discarded it for time being
- Copied `pilz_industrial_motion_planner_planning_pipeline.launch.xml`  from the `prbt_moveit_config/launch` to my `aris_metra_scan_config/launch`.
- Created `cartesian_limits.yaml` file in the `aris_metra_scan_config/config`
- In `aris_metra_scan_config/demo.launch`, I changed  `<arg name="pipeline" default="ompl" />`  to `<arg name="pipeline" default="pilz_industrial_motion_planner" />`
  when I launch demo.launch, I get `MoveGroup running was unable to load pilz_industrial_motion_planner::CommandPlanner`. Help

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-12-14**:
Since comments are not meant for new questions, please accept this answer and post a new question with your new problem.

Try following this tutorial: https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/pilz_industrial_motion_planner.html
And note that you might have to build from the master branch at the moment.

**Comment by [srujan](https://answers.ros.org/users/51644/srujan/) on 2020-12-14**:
That tutorial didn't help. However my issue is resolved now.
I copied `pilz_command_planner_planning_pipeline.launch.xml` from the `prbt_moveit_config/launch` to my `aris_metra_scan_config/launch`

and made the following change in `aris_metra_scan_config/demo.launch`

- `<arg name="pipeline" default="ompl" />` to `<arg name="pipeline" default="pilz_command_planner" />`

This solved the issue.

@fvd, do I still add a new question for this?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-12-14**:
If it's solved, then no (although if the tutorial is insufficient you could try fixing it). Just remember to use comments for clarifications for the future and make a new post for new questions, so that others can find it more easily.

**Comment by [srujan](https://answers.ros.org/users/51644/srujan/) on 2020-12-14**:
I agree and will surely make a new post for new questions in future. Thank you!